# Converting PDF to image via Inkscape breaks fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts, inkscape

I want to convert a PDF page to a PNG image. Following [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15484727) I tried the following command:

```
inkscape <PDF PATH> --export-dpi=300 --export-area-drawing --export-background=#ffffff \
    --pdf-page=<PDF PAGE NUMBER> --export-filename="<IMAGE PATH>"
```

However, any fonts the PDF uses that aren't installed on my system are turned into a default sans serif font in the output image.

**Is there a way to make Inkscape use the fonts embedded in the PDF?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Inkscape tries to match PDF fonts to installed fonts. To fix this, **add the option `--pdf-poppler`, and text will be turned into vector paths before rasterization.** The result, then, is that embedded fonts render whether they're installed or not.

That particular command (and indeed, a general command for converting PDF to an image) would be:

```
inkscape <PDF PATH> --pdf-poppler --export-dpi=300 --export-area-drawing --export-background=#ffffff \
    --pdf-page=<PDF PAGE NUMBER> --export-filename="<IMAGE PATH>"
```

---

This corresponds to checking the uppermost radio button in Inkscape's GUI's PDF import dialogue:

[image: Inkscape import settings. “Poppler/Cairo import: Import via external library. Text consists of groups containing cloned glyphs where each glyph is a path. Images are stored internally. Meshes cause entire document to be rendered as a raster image.”]